# Why my app is supporting Android version greater than Jelly Bean ( 18 )

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio . when I uploaded my  app on google  play store  it supports all the versions started from foryo (7) to kitkat 4.4 ( 20 )

```
 signingConfigs {
}
compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 7
    targetSdkVersion 18
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0'

}
```

Comment: Because target != max.

Comment: you have yourself given minSdk as 7

Comment: I aslo did use maxSdkVersion tag

Comment: Just to follow up on Mike's comment: Google [recommends against](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#max) using `maxSdkVersion`. _"By design, new versions of the platform are fully backward-compatible."_

Comment: yes i know but what is the solution to  this problem

Comment: What's the problem? Why would you want your app to not be usable on more modern platforms? If necessary, the platform will run your app in some kind of compatibility mode.

Comment: Why is it a problem?

Comment: Basically i created a call and msg blocking app , In android version  >  18  you cannot read messages directly  unless u are the default sms app

Comment: Huh? If you're using api calls that are deprecated in versions of Android greater than 18, it will still work. Android will run your app in some sort of compatibility mode if necessary, but the ability to run the app will not disappear.

Comment: @Ted I believe the OP is saying that their app is (at least) half-nonfunctional on API>18. Non-default SMS apps no longer have standard write access to the Provider as of KitKat. (I guess they updated their comment, but they meant "write/delete".)

Comment: @MikeM. - Ah. I see that OP updated the comment after I responded to it. For SMS apps on KitKat, [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html) is required reading.

Comment: @TedHopp Oh, yeah, I pretty much have that URL memorized, as often as I try to explain to users why their SMS apps don't work anymore. :-) But I believe the OP has a legitimate concern; if their app is useless on API>18, why can't they set a maxSdkVersion? As far as I can tell, Gradle doesn't allow/ignores it, and it overrides the manifest.

Answer (score 2):

It will support because targeted Version is not the maximum version to support. 
`android:minSdkVersion="7"` below API level 7 it will not work and `android:targetSdkVersion="18"` it means it can be targeted till API level 18 it will work on above API level 18 also, `Android Improves functionality version to Version` which means it will add some new features to the older version. That is why your app works on newer version too.